# How to do a.Find(after) in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to find a cell with a given key. The data in the sheet is similar to...

```
SECTION1    KEY1
            KEY2
            KEY3
SECTION2    KEY4
```

Although the keys are currently unique, I suspect that may not be the case in the future. So I do two lookups, one on the section in column A:

```
Dim S As Range
Set S = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A:A").Find("SECTION1", , xlValues, xlWhole)
```

And that returns, in this case (14,1). Perfect. But now I try to look for the key using after, which hopefully reduces the chance of a collision:

```
Dim K As Range
Set K = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("B:B").Find("KEY1", S.Cells(S.Row - 1, 2), xlValues, xlWhole)
```

And that returns a type mismatch. Remove the AFTER clause and it works fine. According to [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel), it *seems* this should be a range, but yikes that page is confusing.

I've tried multiple variations for the clause, including S, S.Cells and others, but they all give me a type mismatch. Anyone have a working version and an explanation of what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably thinking of `Offset`, when you are using the `After` parameter. As a rule of a thumb, the `After:=` should be a part of the range of the `.Find`

---

The second problem is that the range `s` is only with one column (and probably one row as well). You are somehow referring a second column here - `S.Cells(S.Row - 1, 2)`, and it does not like it at all. Change the `2` to `1`.

---

To understand what the range should look like, try to print the address of the After, before assigning it in the Find.

`Debug.Print S.Cells(S.Row - 1, 2).Address` should give some cell address within the second column (B) in order to make the whole code working. A hint - if you want the After parameter to be the same row as the found cell in column `A` try something like this - `S.Cells(1,1).Offset(0,1)` for `After:=`.

Comment: Changing the 2 to a 1 still results in a type mismatch. It's not the *value* of the inputs, it's the whole type of the input. Anything I put in there causes this error. Perhaps you can provide an entire line that works?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz - see the updated answer. Put `Debug.Print` and work until you do not see an address which is only in the `B` column.

Comment: I guess that `S.Cells(1,1).Offset(0,1)` should be ok, @MauryMarkowitz

Comment: Ok, I had to try a bunch of things, but yes, its now working. That error is VERY MISLEADING!

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz - congrats for managing yourself :) Concerning this error - the good point about it is that you will only do it once in a lifetime :)

Answer (score 1):

Looking the docs, it says *Notice that After must be a single cell in the range*.

So the After Argument must be a single cell **inside the range where you are searching** (in your example, a cell inside B:B).

Using notation `S.Cells(S.Row - 1, 2)`, yes, you mean the cell inside range B:B and same row that SECTION1, but S is referenced to a cell outside B:B, and probably that's causing the error.

This works for me:

```
Set K = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("B:B").Find("KEY1", Range("B" & S.Cells(1, 1).Row), xlValues, xlWhole)
```

Is the same than yours but notation `Range("B" & S.Cells(1, 1).Row)` makes sure you are referencing to a cell inside B:B.

I know, it's kind of annoying, but it works.